# How do i show mySql data in inverse order

Tags: php, mysql

Update: thanks for the help everyone, the entire code is on the bottom of the text, with brazilian-portuguese comentary.

How exactly do I show the information I have in my tables (using PHP) in reverse order?

For example lets say I have a table with an AUTO_INCREMENT `id` column as primary key and a `name` column:

> id: 1 Name: Cris
>   id: 2 Name: Elen
>   id: 3 Name: Bob
>   id: 4 Name: Lian

I need to show it in the page like this:

> id: 4 Name: Lian
>   id: 3 Name: Bob
>   id: 2 Name: Elen
>   id: 1 Name: Cris

This code only shows them in normal order, so far it works but it isn't exactly what i need.

PS: I used `$result` and `$rows` to count how many rows I had and tried to use it in the `for` function but it didn't work.

```
<?php 
    $conect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Noticias", $conect) or die(mysql_error());

    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titulos", $conect);
    $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    echo "$totalrows Rows test edit<br>";

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['Titulo'];
    echo "<br>";
    }
    for($i=$totalrows;$i>=0;$i-1){
       $_Str ="SELECT Titulo FROM titulos WHERE id_Noticia=".$i."";
       $show = mysql_query($_Str, $conect);
       echo $show['Titulo']."<br>";
    }
?>
```

Ok, you guys solved my problem so it's only fair to show what i was trying to do.

I was trying to get the reverse order because i was wanted to create(as an exercise) a page that saves a blog title and its content.

i needed it to show the blog posts in reverse order so the user can see them from newest to oldest.

i also had to make every blog title to be used as a link to the blog post(right now it only gives a reference to the exacly same link, i'm working on it)

it also has a bit of HTML just to create a area where the posts links will be shown, it shows a max of 12 blog links(3 posts in the same line, then it jumps to the next line) and if a blog post is too big(more than 90px) it covers the rest of the link (title) with dots.

again, sorry for bad english, i'm out of practice.

```
 <?php
 //coneção com o banco de dados onde os dados das nopticias estão salvos
 $conect = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("Noticias", $conect) or die(mysql_error());

    //Calcula quantas noticias existem salvas no banco de dados, pdoe ser usado 
    //quando o usuario quiser ver todas as noticias
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titulos", $conect);
    $totalrows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    //ordena as noticias em ordem decrecente(da mais nova para a mais velha)
    //e salva em um array
    $result2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titulos ORDER BY id_Noticia DESC", $conect);
    $lista = array(); 
    while($row= mysql_fetch_array($result2)) {
    $lista[].=$row['Titulo'];
    }
    //variaveis para manipular quantas noticias aparecerão
    $a=0;
    $b=0;
   ?>
   <html>
    <head>
    <title>Painel de Noticias!!!</title>
    <style>
        //cria a area onde os titulos aparecerão
        .boxed {
        border: 2px solid green ;
        width: 300px;

        }
        //encobre com pontos qualquer parte do titulo que ultrapasse mais de 90 pixels
        .espaco90 {
        width: 90px; 
        float: left;
        overflow: hidden;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        white-space: nowrap;
        }
        </style>
         </head>
         <body>

          <div class="boxed" >
           <p>
            <?php
             //seleciona os titulos e aplica um link para eles, aqui falta um meio de determinar os links para cada
      //titulo existente no banco de dados, más como isso 
       //será usado em conjunto com o wolrd press então eu creio 
       //que não seja necessário aha não ser que você queira
         for($i=0;$i<=$totalrows-1;$i++){
        echo "<div class='espaco90'><a href='http://www.w3schools.com'>".$lista[$i]."</a></div></p><p>";

        $a=$a+1;
        $b=$b+1;
        if($b<12){
        if($a>=3){
            echo "<br>";
            $a=$a-3;
        }
        }else{
            echo"<br>";
            break;
        }
        }
        ?> </p>
        </div>

        </body>
       </html>
```

Comment: Use an `ORDER BY` to tell MySQL which column to order by, and use `DESC` to reverse the order....`SELECT * FROM titulos ORDER BY id DESC`

Comment: As Travesty3 said, use ORDER BY. You could always sort data after you get it, but it's good practice to make the SQL query do the work when you can. SQL is optimized for that, and you're less likely to make a silly goof that mucks things up (as all programmers do at one time or another. *grin*)

Comment: Just add an `ORDER BY id DESC` clause to that first query. The entire `for` loop looks wrong. It seems entirely unnecessary, and its very inefficient (running a separate query for each `id_Noticia` value. And we don't usually have any guarantee that the values in the `id_Noticia` column are going to be contiguous integer values; the design of that `for` loop looks completely broken. The mysql interface is deprecated; you should be using PDO or mysqli for new development.

Comment: I don't really agree with @KathyA. It's just fine to do this kind of basic display ordering in the presentation layer. It's even better if you can get the clients server to the ordering for you!

Comment: @Strawberry: with an appropriate index defined, MySQL can return the results in order more efficiently than the client can sort them. (MySQL can make use of an index to avoid a "sort" operation, it will use the pre-ordered index to retrieve and return the rows in the specified order.)

Comment: @spencer7593 That's true for the initial query. The round trip to the database necessitated by any subsequent re-sorting of that result would likely be slower than handling it all client-side.

Comment: @Strawberry: Yes, that's true. I fail to see the need for subsequent query of the database; it would be inefficient to re-query to get the same exact same set of data, just in a different order. (OP example code shows an unnecessary `for` loop; that loop uses a wrong pattern, with a query inside the loop, and depends on an overly generous assumption that the values in `id_Noticia` will be contiguous integers; that whole `for` loop doesn't belong there. One query of the database is sufficient; the `while (fetch)` pattern is appropriate; all OP needs is to add an `ORDER BY` to the first query.

Comment: I already fixed the code @spencer7593 , i was using the for loop because it was for something else later on, i'll update with the corret code i have now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

```
SELECT * FROM titulos ORDER BY id_Noticia DESC
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

MySQL will return the rows in the specified sequence. (The `DESC` keyword indicates that the rows are to be returned in descending order, with the highest values first.)

Get rid of `for` loop and it's contents. The `while ( fetch )` is the right pattern.

---

**NOTE:** PHP **mysql_** interface is deprecated. New development should be using either **PDO** or **mysqli** interface.

Answer (score 1):

This should get items in reverse order

```
$_Str ="SELECT Titulo FROM titulos WHERE ORDER BY id_Noticia DESC "; 
$show = mysql_query($_Str, $conect); 
for($i=0; $i<$totalrows; $i+1) { 
    echo $show[i]['Titulo']."<br>";
}
```

Comment: it didnt work, maybe i should change some stuff in the for statement

Comment: Take the select statement and query out of the loop `$_Str ="SELECT Titulo FROM titulos WHERE ORDER BY id_Noticia DESC "; $show = mysql_query($_Str, $conect); for($i=0;$i<$totalrows;$i+1){ echo $show[i]['Titulo']."<br>";}`

Comment: @LIUFA: this should use a `while fetch` loop; not a `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM titulos ORDER BY id_Noticia DESC", $conect);
```

You can learn about `ORDER BY ... DESC` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can use array_reverse() function after getting your data to your data structure. Here is an implementation of array_reverse function:

```
<?php
$a=array("a"=>"Volvo","b"=>"BMW","c"=>"Toyota");
print_r(array_reverse($a));
?>
```

For more info visit the link: http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_reverse.asp